# 「だね」「だよね」と「のだね」「のだよね」の違い

Tags: sentence-final-particles, no-da

以前、この四つの文の違いをネーティブに尋ねてみました。

1. 「あまり好きじゃない**ね**」
2. 「あまり好きじゃない**よね**」
3. 「あまり好きじゃない**んだね**」
4. 「あまり好きじゃない**んだよね**」

その人によると、「ね」と「んだよね」の文は自分の好みを他人に話している感じで、「んだね」の文は話し相手から聞いた情報を自分で言い返している感じで、「よね」の文は他人の好みについて自分の推測か、相手の言ったことの解釈を話している感じだということです。さらには、「ね」と「んだよね」の違いを尋ねてみたら、「ね」の方が断定が強く、「んだよね」の方が柔らかいと答えてもらいました。

「ね」は自分のことを、「よね」は他人のことを話しているのは納得できますが、なぜ「のだ」を入れるだけでそれが逆になるのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ポイントは、「んだよ」と「よね」がいずれもチャンク (chunk) として機能することと、「んだよね」を「んだよ＋ね」と「んだ＋よね」のいずれに解釈するかです。

お話のインフォーマントの方の解釈は「んだよ＋ね」(4a)、つまり、ある文に「ね」がくっついた構造であって、その「ある文」というのが「んだよ」で終わる形、つまり第１の文と同じく話し手の領分の情報を内容とする文なので同じように機能するというわけです。

これを「んだ＋よね」と解釈した場合(4b)は、第２の文と同じように相手に尋ねる感じになります。この場合の第２の文との違いは、２が単にそのように推測しているのに対して、４は聞き手の領分のある言動をそのような趣旨、意味合いだと解釈したということになります。なので、４の方が根拠がある感じがします。

「んだ」が表すものは第３の文と４bが共通で聞き手の事情の解釈、４aが話し手の事情の説明になります。３の「んだね」の形は「んだな」に比べてあまり話し手の事情の説明にはなりにくいです。